# FOS Elastica bundle populate command killed by oom_reaper with out of memory

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

There are 1,8 million records in the database table that I want to index through the fos:elastica:populate command. As soon as ~500.000 documents are already in the elasticsearch the indexing stops abruptly.

In the dmesg on backend server I saw this:

```
[19314221.670723] Out of memory: Killed process 2640772 (php) total-vm:21738676kB, anon-rss:19847596kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:42352kB oom_score_adj:0
[19314224.812907] oom_reaper: reaped process 2640772 (php), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Elasticsearch, MySQL and PHP Symfony backend (where populate runs) are on different servers.

How can I fix that and fill elastica with documents?

FOSElasticaBundle is v5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. The only solution I found (excluding the possibility of renting a powerful server) is to run the populate command with a bash script in parts.

Here is a sample script to index the remaining data.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {6000..18000..4000}
  do 
    bin/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --first-page="$i" --last-page="$((i + 4000))"
  done
bin/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --first-page=18000
```